# Properly Measuring I/O Time When Benchmarking

Tags: c++, performance, io, profiling

I have a question regarding measuring I/O time (disk, internet network, etc) on my program. How can I achieve it?

Let me give you what I'm thinking. Suppose I have a C++ program with the following logic.

```
...
1: auto start = chrono::now()
2: io_ops()
3: auto duration = (chrono::now() - start).count()
...
```

The are multiple issue with the approach. First, before executing instruction in line 3, the CPU might be congested, which I don't consider that as I/O time (or should I?). Second issue might come when the CPU reorder instructions since there is no dependency or any data hazard. Now, I'm wondering, is there any standard practice to measure I/O time?

Thanks in advance and Merry Xmas!

Answer (score 0):

When measuring I/O external to the CPU (disk, network), instruction reordering isn't a thing; instructions take nanoseconds, and disk I/O takes milliseconds - 10<sup>6</sup> times slower.

What matters with external I/O is the total amount of data transferred, transfer chunk size and queue depth.

Additionally with disk I/O, read/write, sequential/random access and data caching play a role.

The standard way to measure disk I/O is to get the system as idle as possible and run a number of iterations of the test (transferring a sufficiently large amount of data), varying the chunk size, then calculate the average time per iteration.

From the resulting 2D data set, mapping transfer time to chunk size, compute the I/O metrics - throughput and latency.